# Identify the current file / line that corresponds to a position from a previous git commit

Tags: git, diff

Suppose I have a branch in a git repository. The history of the branch might look something like this:

```
A <- [...] <- Z
```

Now let's say I have a position `P` (e.g. `src/index.js:122`) that refers to a line from the `A` commit.

Between commits `A` and `Z`, commits might refactor the file referenced by the hunk, modify the line slightly (e.g. adding a new argument to a function signature), or even move the file itself to somewhere else in the repository tree. I would like to determine the position `P'` that reflects where that line is in commit `Z`.

Is there a git command that will help me determine this new position?

Comment: Git always works backwards, so the task is much easier if you identify the position of the line in Z, and then have Git figure out the position of the line in A. The `git blame` command does this kind of thing internally. I don't think there's an easy way to expose the computed line numbers, though. The `git log` command does this as well, with `-L`, but the algorithms in `git log` are not as good as the ones in `git blame`. Still, `git log` gets you almost what you want, just in the wrong direction (Z to A).

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is showing annotations made on code, even as the code morphs over time. So it would be quite low-performance, I believe, to continually work backwards; maybe I can cache it though. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using `git blame` and taking a reverse approach, as suggested by torek. This works for my use case as I am attempting to show metadata alongside a file in a git repository, so I know the set of lines I'd like to find original positions for. Assuming that `A` is an ancestor commit of `Z`, we can do the following:

`git blame -fns Z -- api/v3/views.py`

This will give commit hashes, original tree paths, and line numbers for each line in the file, e.g.

```
481daae85d6 api/v3/files/views.py   2   4) from rest_framework.response import Response
^           ^                       ^   ^
$1          $2                      $3  $4
```

Let's denote a position as `<hash>:<path>@<line>`. This shows us that `Z:api/v3/views.py@4` originally showed up as `481daae85d6:api/v3/files/views.py:2`.

Last step: the position `P` we've identified in `A` might not be the original commit that included that line, which will lead to false negatives. When importing these meta annotations, we can do another git blame for that specific line in that commit to determine the original commit:

`git blame -fns -L <line>,<line> A -- <path>`

Then we can store the annotation on the returned commit hash, rather than `A`.

The open question here is whether this will be *enough*: code annotations will likely still be relevant even if a line was modified slightly, while this approach will cause these annotations to be "lost".

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `git log -S`. Give it the line as the argument to -S. If the line hasn’t changed, this should find it.

From the "git log" man page:

```
   -S<string>
       Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the
       specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for
       the scripter’s use.

       It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a
       struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first
       came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the
       interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going
       until you get the very first version of the block.

       Binary files are searched as well.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I'm interested in finding the corresponding line, even if it's changed. For example, the original line might be `let x = 123`, and I'd want to find the matching line even if it's been changed to `const x = 123` or `let x = 456`.

Having said that, I'm not sure there's a crisp definition of what constitutes "the same line" here. I'm hoping we can deal with some changes though!

Comment: Also, would this work for the case when the line is simply moved in the file? The number of occurrences would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I would suggest is :

Inspect the output of

```
git diff A Z -- src/index.js
```

You can inspect it by hand, or process the output with a script, to spot how line 122 was shifted between `A` and `Z` with this view of the differences.

---

If the evolution of said line is too intricate, you may want to inspect :

```
git log A..Z -p -- src/index.js
# or :
git log A..Z --reverse -p -- src/index.js
```

You will see all the individual evolutions of said file, and, likewise, you can compute how the initial line 122 evolves till `Z`.